# Is there any way to specialize a generic function for a specific type with no arguments?

Tags: rust

So I have a trait which has a generic function which operates over any type:

```
trait MyTrait {
  fn foo<T>();
}
```

I want to specialize this function so there is an override if a specific type is passed to it.  So for instance, something like this:

```
struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn foo<T>() {
        println!("Trait foo");
    }
}

struct B {}

impl A {
    fn foo<T>() where T: B {
        println!("Specialized foo");
    }
}
```

Such that:

```
A::foo::<B>();
```

Would print: `Specialized foo`

But when I try to compile this, I get the error on the where clause:

> error[E0404]: expected trait, found struct `B`

Is there any way to achieve this?  In Swift I could do something like this:

```
struct A {
    static func foo<T>(_ t: T.Type) { ... }
    static func foo(_ t: B.Type) { ... }
}

A.foo(B.self)
```

Is there anything similar, or any other way to achieve this in Rust?

Comment: Does `foo` in your actual code need to use `self` at all?

Comment: No it does not use `self`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution requires a **nightly** Rust compiler, and an unstable feature *specialization*. The compiler will rightfully warn you:

> warning: the feature `specialization` is incomplete and may not be safe to use and/or cause compiler crashes

Since you don't require using either `self` or `T` in function `foo`, for it to work you should make the trait generic from `T`, thus `MyTrait<T>` and then implement its default case and specialized cases for `A`

```
#![feature(specialization)]

struct A;
struct B;

trait MyTrait<T> {
  fn foo();
}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for A {
    default fn foo() {
        println!("Trait foo");
    }
}

impl MyTrait<B> for A {
    fn foo() {
        println!("Specialized foo");
   }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{};
    <A as MyTrait::<i32>>::foo(); // Trait foo
    <A as MyTrait::<B>>::foo(); // Specialized foo
}
```

The latter ugly part `<A as MyTrait::<B>>::foo()` is required, because there's no other way to specify which of the specializations you mean.

If you want, however to use an object of type `T` as an argument of `foo`, you'll have to specialize not for a specific type `B`, but for a specific other trait. Here I made a `DummyMark` that is only implemented by `B`

```
#![feature(specialization)]

struct A;
struct B;

trait MyTrait<T> {
  fn foo(&self, obj: &T);
}

trait DummyMark {}
impl DummyMark for B {}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for A {
    default fn foo(&self, obj: &T) {
        println!("Trait foo");
    }
}

impl<T: DummyMark> MyTrait<T> for A {
    fn foo(&self, obj: &T) {
        println!("Specialized foo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A{};
    a.foo(&42); // Trait foo
    a.foo(&B{}); // Specialized foo
}
```

Comment: Any negative feedback is welcome in the comments down here

Comment: Use `min_specialization`.